# Why can the numpy method work on pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, oop, numpy, interface

This is more like a object oriented question.

I am using numpy and pandas in python. Say I read a shopping list into a pd type. And now I want to find the mean value of all the stuff.

```
data = pd.read_csv('shopping.csv')
prices = data['priceTag']
```

Then I tried two ways to return the mean price. Looks like both of them are working fine.

```
mean_price = prices.mean()
mean_price = np.mean(prices)
```

Then why the np method can work on the pd type?

Comment: .mean() is a method of the Pandas Dataframe class while np.mean() is a method of the default Numpy library.
No parameters need to be passed to the pandas object as the method acts on underlying data while the Numpy method requires and object be passed to it.

Comment: @Q.Holness, I updated my question, actually, I want to ask, why the np method could work on pd type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

> a : array_like Array containing numbers whose mean is desired. If a is
>   not an array, a conversion is attempted.

Read especially the second sentence. If `a` is not a `numpy` `array` already, the `numpy` `mean` function will try to call `np.array(a)`.

Answer (score 4):

here is the source code of numpy mean:

```
def mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
"""
doc for function 

"""
if type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
    try:
        mean = a.mean
        return mean(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
    except AttributeError:
        pass

return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                      out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

actually when you call np.mean(data), you are calling data.mean()

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. Calling np.array would make the DataFrame a numpy array.